# Reading field value in custom submit action of list

Tags: sitecore-forms

I am struggling to get the selected value of a list inside a Sitecore Forms 9.1 custom submit action.

The value I am seeing is:

```
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]
```

From the various samples on the Internet - I have tried using:

```
return field?.GetType().GetProperty("Value")?.GetValue(field, null)?.ToString() ?? string.Empty;
```

and

```
var postedField = (IValueField)viewModel;
IValueField valueField = postedField as IValueField;
PropertyInfo property = postedField.GetType().GetProperty("Value");
object postedValue = (object)property != null ? property.GetValue((object)postedField) : (object)null;
```

Which works fine for text values, but not for the selected radio button or checkbox from a list.

I could just check if the type is a list/collection and iterate over the values but just wanted to check if there was something cleaner already out there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mentioned it is working for `text value` so for `dropdown` you can use below code and similar condition you can use for `radio button` and `checkbox` using corresponding view model.

```
var field= GetFieldById(data.dropdownFieldId, formSubmitContext.Fields);
string dropdownValue=GetValue(field);


private static IViewModel GetFieldById(Guid id, IList<IViewModel> fields)
        {
            return fields.FirstOrDefault(f => Guid.Parse(f.ItemId) == id);
        }

private static string GetValue(object field)
        {

            if (field is DropDownListViewModel)
            {
                DropDownListViewModel dropdownField = field as DropDownListViewModel;
                string selectedtext = dropdownField.Value.FirstOrDefault();
                return selectedtext;
            }
             // Similar condition you can apply for checkbox using CheckBoxViewModel

            return field?.GetType().GetProperty("Value")?.GetValue(field, null)?.ToString() ?? string.Empty;
        }
```